# Correct way to finish QT app. Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt

I'm studiyng Qt and C++ and trying to make a simple Qt application. I don't understand how to destroy classes correctly. I need the destructor of MainWidget to be called to stop the timer. But when I try to delete MainWidget I'm getting "segmentation fault". Can somebody help to understand how to do this in right way?

**GUI.cpp**

```
#include "GUI.hpp"

Gui::Gui()
{
    led = new Led();
    mainWidget = new MainWidget();
    mainWidget->show();

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendOneSignal()),
               mainWidget, SLOT(slotFunc()));
}

Gui::~Gui()
{

    delete led;
    //delete mainWidget; //segmentation error occurs
}

void Gui::func(void)
{
    emit sendOneSignal();
}
```

**GUI.hpp**

```
#ifndef __GUI_HEADER__
#define __GUI_HEADER__

#include "Led.hpp"
#include "MainWidget.hpp"

class Gui : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Gui();
    ~Gui();
    void func(void);
signals:
     void sendOneSignal(void);

private:
    Led *led;
    MainWidget *mainWidget;

};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Gui> GuiPtr;

#endif /* __GUI_HEADER__ */
```

**MainWidget.cpp**

```
#include "MainWidget.hpp"

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
    
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWidget::onTimeChanged);
    timer->start(1000);

    cardLabel = new QLabel();
    cardLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTop);
    cardLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/img"));
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
    timer->stop();
    delete timer;
    delete cardLabel;
}

void MainWidget::onTimeChanged()
{
////
}

void MainWidget::slotFunc()
{
///
}
```

**MainWidget.hpp**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

//#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFile>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>

typedef std::unique_ptr<QMessageBox> MessageBoxPtr;

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWidget();

protected slots:
    void slotFunc();

private slots:
    void onTimeChanged();

private:
    QLabel *cardLabel;
    QTimer *timer;
    QVBoxLayout *vbox;
    QHBoxLayout *hbox;
    bool isMessageBoxClosed = true;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

Comment: I'm general by setting parent objects you don't need to use `delete` in qt

Comment: @AlanBirtles So, how I can make the destructor of MainWidget to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to `delete` a `QWidget`, or any other `QObject`, if it had a parent set. It will be done by parent's destruction.

That's the reason why studying Qt *and* C++ at same time   is confusing. Qt  throws out most of pudent C++ patterns out of window (not-a-widget), staying on very narrow subset of C++, until recently it was C++98, now it's C++11.

If you *really* wish to delete some parented or connected (signal\slot) `QObject` early or dynamically, you have to use `deleteLater()` method. The name is misleading, if possible it would delete immediately, but otherwise it will queue deletion until message pump finishes its cycle. For same reason you almost never should declate a `QObject` as a direct member of another `QObject` - default destructor behaviour would cause same problem.

Destructors would be called. Just not by you. The reason it's done this way is that the framework is multithreaded and parent will call methods ("slots") of a child object via signal\slot system. If you delete a child object, the parent would have a dangling pointer in its store.

So,t he root of the problem is creation of `MainWidget`. Because there is such code,

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWidget::onTimeChanged);
```

it should be either created with parent given:

```
mainWidget = new MainWidget(this); // can't be done here, this is not QWidget
```

or destroyed:

```
mainWidget->deleteLater();
```

Even connection to itself counts because event processing is global.

The problem here is: A `Gui` isn't a `QWidget` and a a `QWidget` cannot be parented to a `QObject`. It's rather unusual to have a `QObject` hosting widgets. It's normally done by a top-level widget.

NB: you shall not use GUI elements in other threads. If purpose of creating a host `QObject` was to pass\move it to a worker thread, there are more icebergs hiding in Qt on that route. IF not impossible, it's very inconvinient.

Comment: The problem is ~MainWidget() is not called when I stopped the program. Is this ok, that I put *mainWidget pointer as private member of GUI class?

Comment: @Alex did you parent it to `Gui`? you didn't. Presense of `typedef std::unique_ptr<Gui> GuiPtr;` also a suspect.  You should declare unique_ptr with a proper deleter with `deleteLater()`, again, or you should use Qt's pointer.. or you never should use smart pointers if you  are not sure how. That's why I said that Qt and classic C++ learing are confusing. They contradict each other. Qt's pattern is that only top-level windets are destroyed explicitly, that's usually a single `MainWindow` in `main()` function.

Comment: Thank you @Swift - Friday Pie, you say "NB: you shall not use GUI elements in other threads.". Yes, the goal was to have a class that can control the LEDs and the screen from another thread. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Alex Yes, the, simplest (and funny thing, right now I'm working on code which does that), is to signal from one thread to GUI thread. In your case you can pass data via argument, e.g. as flags. Otherwise you can use a shared data structure. If you absolutely should invoke a slot in GUI thread directly, use QMetaObject, invoke (see docs). Limitation is due to on some platforms GUI sub-system is ultimately single-threaded and OpenGL\DirectX render APIs are too. Windows is a white crow in that area